# Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled when trying to use a library

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
    enter code hereModule build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:\Users\Ryan\aff_website\node_modules\react-group-table\src\groupTable.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (20:14):

  18 |   renderTeams () {
  19 |     return this.props.teams.map((team, i) => {
> 20 |       return <Row
     |              ^
  21 |         cutOffPosition={this.isTeamInCutoffPosition(i + 1)}
  22 |         dangerZone={this.isTeamInDangerZone(i + 1)}
  23 |         key={i}

Add @babel/preset-react (https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/packages/babel-preset-react) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx (https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/packages/babel-plugin-syntax-jsx) to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.
    at instantiate (C:\Users\Ryan\aff_website\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:72:32)
    at constructor (C:\Users\Ryan\aff_website\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:359:12)
    at Parser.raise (C:\Users\Ryan\aff_website\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:3339:19)
    at Parser.expectOnePlugin (C:\Users\Ryan\aff_website\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:3396:18)
    at Parser.parseExprAtom (C:\Users\Ryan\aff_website\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:13078:18)
    at Parser.parseExprSubscripts (C:\Users\Ryan\aff_website\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:12648:23)
    at Parser.parseUpdate (C:\Users\Ryan\aff_website\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:12627:21)
    at Parser.parseMaybeUnary (C:\Users\Ryan\aff_website\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:12598:23)
    at Parser.parseMaybeUnaryOrPrivate (C:\Users\Ryan\aff_website\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:12392:61)
    at Parser.parseExprOps (C:\Users\Ryan\aff_website\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:12399:23)
```

I have been stuck on this for hours, not sure how to proceed. Please let me know how to fix it if you have any ideas!

Comment: Do you have a `.babelrc`  file  or a `webpack.config.js`?

Comment: Also `package.json`?

Comment: @qrsngky I have webpack.config.js and package.json, not sure where .babelrc would be if I have it

Comment: Any `babel.config.js` or `babel.config.json`?

Comment: @qrsngky no I don't have either, should I make one?

Comment: @RyanHuard can you edit your code and add webpack.config.js and package.json? specifically in your package.json if you have a field name "babel"

Comment: What are the `rules` inside your webpack.config.js? And which version of webpack is listed in package.json?